# continuous processing

Tags: .net, architecture

I'm looking for suggestions on how to best have a continuously running processing engine that runs to process a job queue.

Basically, external clients can add jobs to a queue (via .net or WCF calls).
This needs to return quickly and will be called often, so it just receives the request and adds it to the queue.

The processing engine should be a single process that runs continuously and processes the queue (without being directly called) in order based on a bunch of biz logic.

How can we best create this continuously running process?

- Is it possible to do this stably in asp.net?
- Would it be better to do this as a WCF hosted by Windows Service?
- Other suggestions or methods to accomplish this?

Thanks for reading this and I appreciate your help and suggestions

Note:

I've been using MSMQ to pass the data. 
Is there anyway that you can automatically invoke a process to run on receipt of the message (or if there are messages in the MSMQ queue (I don't know much about MSMQ)).

For example, client A sends MSMQ message to client B via queue Q. Q was empty. Client B now has a message in the Q.

How do I invoke a method to process this? How to host the client that receives the message?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think MSMQ is what you are exactly looking for. One of its important tasks is ensuring reliable delivery. It is easy to use it in .Net and the best thing you will love about it is that there is a WCF binding for it.

Comment: I've been using MSMQ to pass the data.  Is there anyway that you can automatically invoke a process to run on receipt of the message (or if there are messages in the MSMQ queue (I don't know much about MSMQ)).
For example, client A sends MSMQ message to client B via queue Q.  Q was empty.  Client B now has a message in the Q.  How do I invoke a method to process this?

The issue that I've been running into is how to process items in the queue?  Do you need a continuous processing engine to process the queue or is this built into it somehow?
Do you have any good links on this?

Comment: You don't need to poll the queue in WCF. Net.msmq listener will do that for you.

Comment: Look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/WCFMSMQ.aspx), [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tomholl/archive/2008/07/12/msmq-wcf-and-iis-getting-them-to-play-nice-part-1.aspx) and [that](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752246.aspx)  [I recommend this for getting familiar with related terminology](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163357.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

A windows service that will process the queue is the classic way to do this. It has many benefits, including the ability to start up on reboots, good scriptability for management (WMI), so it will also be the preferred choice by sysadmins.

Keep it separate from your WCF service - you should use that for putting jobs on the queue.

Answer (score 2):

> Is it possible to do this stably in asp.net?

Yes, it is possible.  However, if you're passing a lot of data, the option below may be better, as you have more options for communication channels.

> Would it be better to do this as a WCF hosted by Windows Service?

This is likely the best option.  This would give you the option of using higher performance communication channels (to help the throughput of your "many requests"), good control, etc.  It's also much lower overhead, since you don't need to setup IIS for it to run if you self-host.

Comment: That's very helpful. We're not passing much data but will have a lot of requests.  Out of curiosity, how can you do this stably in .net?

Comment: @Summit: WCF has many built-in features for stability and reliability.  As long as you properly handle exceptions, this tends to be incredibly stable.

Comment: Sorry, I just realized my question was unclear, I initially meant can you do this stably in asp.net :)  I just realized I put .net instead of asp.net.  Thanks for your help

Comment: @Summit: Yes, you can do it in a stable manner in ASP.NET - same issues apply...  However, it's adding another layer - if you share the ASP.NET process with other "apps", any of them can pull down ASP.NET.  But if it's just hosting you, then it should be quite stable.